# How to create insert trigger on table?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have table `warehouse`:

```
++++++++++++++
+ id + count +
++++++++++++++
+ 1  + 10    +
++++++++++++++
+ 10 + 100   +
++++++++++++++
+ 3  + 200   +
++++++++++++++
```

I want to create trigger, so if I insert data with value, which exists in table, count of this row will be updated just and new row wouldn't be inserted. If there are no data in table with such id, then new row must be added.

Expected result:

After query:

```
INSERT INTO Warehouse (id, count) VALUES (1, 15);
```

Warehouse table contents will be:

```
++++++++++++++
+ id + count +
++++++++++++++
+ 1  + 25    +
++++++++++++++
+ 10 + 100   +
++++++++++++++
+ 3  + 200   +
++++++++++++++
```

After this query:

```
INSERT INTO Warehouse (id, count) VALUES (8, 11);
```

Warehouse contents would become:

```
++++++++++++++
+ id + count +
++++++++++++++
+ 1  + 25    +
++++++++++++++
+ 10 + 100   +
++++++++++++++
+ 3  + 200   +
++++++++++++++
+ 8  + 11    +
++++++++++++++
```

After this:

```
INSERT INTO Warehouse (id, count) VALUES (3, 5);
```

Warehouse contents would become:

```
++++++++++++++
+ id + count +
++++++++++++++
+ 1  + 25    +
++++++++++++++
+ 10 + 100   +
++++++++++++++
+ 3  + 205   +
++++++++++++++
+ 8  + 11    +
++++++++++++++
```

I am using MySQL 5.1.

### Update

What if I use such approach to insert something into Warehouse table?

```
INSERT INTO 
    Warehouse
    (
        count,
        id
    )
    SELECT 
        count,
        id
    FROM 
        ShopOrderGoods
    WHERE 
        order_id = 1
```

Is it possible to get such behaviour as I want with that approach?

Comment: After `INSERT INTO Warehouse (id, count) VALUES (3, 5);` no changes?

Comment: Ofc there are) I forget to set up new count. My bad.

Comment: You'll want to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (assuming that `id` is a unique (probably primary) key)

Comment: @PatrickQ should I use before update or after update trigger?

Comment: @Sharikov: it's **not** possible to achieve the behavior you describe with a **trigger** in MySQL, due to MySQL restrictions on triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not support `INSTEAD OF` trigger; that is, it's not possible to do this with a trigger.

Assuming the `id` column is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table (or at a minimum, a `UNIQUE KEY` on the table) you can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` form of the `INSERT` statement to achieve the behavior you describe.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Warehouse (id, count) VALUES (1, 15)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + VALUES(`count`);
```

MySQL will attempt the insert, and if that throws a "duplicate key" exception, then the UPDATE action will be attempted. In the example above, the current value of the `count` column will have the new value supplied for that column (in the VALUES clause of the insert) added to it.

(NOTE: If the current value of the `count` column is NULL, or the value being inserted is NULL, then a NULL will be assigned to the `count` column. If you want to handle a NULL value as being zero, then you could enhance the expression to handle those cases:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = IFNULL(`count`,0) + IFNULL(VALUES(`count`),0)
```

**N.B.** If there is another column in the table that has the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property, the auto increment for the table will be increased for each insert attempt, including those where the dupliate key exception is thrown.

**UPDATE**

(based on UPDATE of question)

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` form the INSERT will work with an `INSERT ... SELECT` just like it does with `INSERT ... VALUES`.

```
INSERT INTO Warehouse (count,id)
SELECT s.count, s.id
 FROM ShopOrderGoods s
WHERE s.order_id = 1
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Warehouse`.`count` = `Warehouse`.`count` + VALUES(`count`);
```

(In the first example in my answer, I enclosed the column name "count" in backticks, because I'm not sure if **`COUNT`** is a reserved word. It looks like a reserved word, but I didn't check the list. In this last example, I've not enclosed the column name in backticks. I don't ever use "count" as a column name or alias.)
t use never name )

Comment: So there are no possibility to create trigger, like in SQL server, right? I remember I was using MERGE construction... Look update of my question, please.

Comment: @Sharikov: It's possible to create a trigger in MySQL. But it's not possible to create a trigger that performs the operations you described, due to restrictions MySQL imposes on triggers: firstly, it's not possible to modify rows in the table that the trigger references (in the `ON` clause of the trigger definition), and secondly, MySQL does not support the `INSTEAD OF` type trigger that would be used to implement this behavior in other databases (e.g. Oracle).

Comment: Ok. I got this. Is there a way to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in my approach (look update of my question, please)? I use results of one query in another insert query.

Comment: I am trying to use what you suggested and getting this: http://i.gyazo.com/be5fef04a8b135000a5754099c60dd13.png + are you sure I have to use this: `count = count + VALUES(count)`? May be this: ``count = count + VALUES(s.count)`? But anyway same result :(